# reading numbers separated by space from a file in c

Tags: scanf

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int x,y,t,q;
    char ch;
    fp=fopen("sth.xyt","r");
    while ((fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d %d",&x,&y,&t,&q))!=0)
        printf("x=%d y=%d theta=%d quality=%d\n",x,y,t,q);
        ch=getchar();
//  fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d %d",&x,&y,&t,&q);
//  printf("x=%d y=%d theta=%d quality=%d",x,y,t,q);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here sth.xyt has multiple lines.
 Each line contains 4 number separated by spaces.
example
115 757 180 6
144 191 214 17
170 114 202 6
182 253 236 80
195 377 56 83
The problem is that loop is running infinitely .
Also I used getchar so that when user presses enter key then next line is read from file  . That's not happening .
Currently my output is
 
an infinite series of 
x=195 y=377 theta=56 quality=83

Answer (score 0):

Found it from [How to find EOF through fscanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048576/how-to-find-eof-through-fscanf)

I should put !=EOF instead of above !=0 in above code.

Still that getchar is not working as it should.