# fscanf to read a file with - and unix paths

Tags: c++, scanf

I am trying to read a file called test_read.txt that contains below line w

> ```
> load_data -filename /user/bin/script/file1.txt -nosplit somepath.somefile.somearray
> load_data -filename /user/bin/script/runscript/file2.txt -nosplit somepath.somefile.somearray.somememory
> ```

to read this I am using below code

```
char nouse [50];
char filename [1000];
char str_char [500];
FILE *file_list = NULL;

if (file_list == NULL) {
  file_list = fopen("test_read.txt", "r");
  std::cout << "Hello read file!" << std::endl;
  while(fscanf(file_list, "%s %s %s %s %s", nouse,nouse,filename,nouse, str_char) !=EOF) {
    std::cout << "file name is " << filename << "memory name is" << str_char;
  }
}
```

the loop wont print after "hello read file". I see this line printed and nothing after that. What am I doing wrong?

Will fscanf and char type array that is filename read the whole filename path with "/" and array path with "." in between and store as one variable?

used above snippet of code to open and scan file that has unix path and some memory elements listed in hierarchical path.

Comment: `fscanf()` doesn't return EOF.  So `while(fscanf(...) !=EOF)` will **always** be true...

Comment: Also there is a missing semicolon after the second `std::cout` line, and you aren't including `std::endl` at the end of the message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048576/how-to-find-eof-through-fscanf this thread has a snippet that uses very similar code.

Comment: It's not a "thread" - please take the [tour] and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**, because that has many implications for how things work here.

Comment: @JohnGordon Wrong. `EOF` is one possible return value from `fscanf`. It's usually not what you want to test for, but still, it's in the mix. Your **always** is correct until `stdin` is closed.

Comment: If I add the missing `<< std::endl;` to the second cout line, this code gives me the expected output (two lines after the Hello line) on this input.

Comment: @JohnGordon [point](https://godbolt.org/z/nrohnjcGh) (with erroneous checking - but still EOF).

Comment: Why are you still using "C" style file I/O and string handling?